# How can I override $routeProvider and reload the page?

Tags: angularjs

I want to override AngularJS $routeProvider and reload the page. I tried adding `target="_self"` to the `<a>` tag, but it doesn't work. The angular site has the following solution:

> The $location service allows you to change only the URL; it does not allow you to reload the page. When you need to change the URL and reload the page or navigate to a different page, please use a lower level API, $window.location.href.

Okay, so how do I use this? It kind of just left me hanging. Where do I put `$window.location.href`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$window is an injectable service, just like $location. So, at the place where you currently inject $location and call its path() method, inject $window instead and set $window.location.href to the URL you want to load.

Comment: Thanks! It seems that using ``target="_self"`` is a simpler solution though. Apparently I had an error in my code, but it's nice to know how to use this solution.